# How to exclude URL in web.xml with # in the url-pattern

Tags: web.xml

```
<!-- Security constraint to require the users to login using Google authentication -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**Public Link**

I want to exclude this url with # in included but it is not working. The first filter always gets executed. How to do this?

```
<!-- Security constraint for public link -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/#/optout/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```